# Restsharp and deserializing derived types

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, restsharp

Consider the following XML:

```
<events xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" artist="Rammstein"    festivalsonly="0" page="1" perPage="50" totalPages="1" total="25">
    <event xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
        <id>1985967</id>
        <title>Rammstein: "Made in Germany 1995 -2011 LIVE"</title>
        <artists>
            <artist>Rammstein</artist>
            <artist>Deathstars</artist>
            <headliner>Rammstein</headliner>
        </artists>
    </event>
</events>
```

I want to deserialize all the tags under `artists` into a single list. What I have so far:

```
public class Artist
{
    public string Value { get; set; }
}

public class HeadLiner : Artist
{

}

public class ArtistCollection : List<Artist>
{

}

public class Event
{
    public ArtistCollection Artists { get; set; }
}
```

I was hoping to end up with a List containing 3 items here (two artists and one headliner) but I'm only getting the artists. Is it possible to get this kind of behaviour working out of the box with Restsharp? Or do I need a custom serializer?

Using attributes, I think I'd need the `XmlInclude` attribute, but I'm loving the 'out of the box'-part of Restsharp so far.

Answer (score 0):

From the date of your post I'm probably a bit late, but better late than never.

I believe your xml needs to be more like this:

```
<events xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#" artist="Rammstein"    festivalsonly="0" page="1" perPage="50" totalPages="1" total="25">
   <event xmlns:geo="http://www.w3.org/2003/01/geo/wgs84_pos#">
       <id>1985967</id>
       <title>Rammstein: "Made in Germany 1995 -2011 LIVE"</title>
       <artists>
           <artist>Rammstein</artist>
           <artist>Deathstars</artist>
           <artist xsi:type="headliner">Rammstein</artist>
       </artists>
   </event>
</events>
```

Comment: That makes sense, but sadly I am not the supplier of the XML